# ¿ como Sacar porcentaje en sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql

este es mi consulta

```
porcentaje = isnull((
        select sum(x.valor)*100/(select sum(ccc.Valor)
                from CuentasPorCobrar ccc)
                from CuentaCorriente x
                    where   x.Detalle like 'Pago%'
                    ),0)
```

x.Valor = -5250.00

ccc.Valor = 1000.00
el resutaldo que me lanza es: -525.00

pero quiero sacar el porcentaje = 19.04

Comment: Regla de tres básica: ¿Si 5250 es el 100%, 1000 qué porcentaje será? `(ccc.Valor * 100) / ABS(x.valor)`

Comment: gracias por la ayuda

Comment: No tiene relación con la pregunta, pero no puedo dejar pasar que, considerando los nombres que utiliza tu consulta, estás trabajando con cuentas corrientes en un sistema contable o de cobro. Te recomiendo discretizar el tipo de movimiento de cada registro con un campo exclusivo para ello, o bastará que alguno de los registros comiencen con un detalle distinto a "Pago" para quedar fuera de tu set de resultados.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

buenas, espero te sirva

```
porcentajeIngCuen = isnull((
select sum(ccc.valor)*100/(select sum(x.Valor)*-1
        from CuentaCorriente x
            where   x.Detalle like 'Pago%')
        from CuentasPorCobrar ccc
            ),0),
```

Answer (score 2):

Quizá un poco tarde, ojalá a alguien le sirva:

```
SELECT cast(isnull(Round((
        select (100/sum(x.valor))*(select sum(ccc.Valor)
                from CuentasPorCobrar ccc)
                from CuentaCorriente x
                    where   x.Detalle like 'Pago%'
                    ),2),0)as varchar(5))+ ' ' +'%' as Porcentaje
```